# Common LISP function that deletes the element at the n-th position of each sub-list within a list

Tags: list, common-lisp

I've been messing around with common LISP for a couple of weeks now, mostly attempting to practice recursion. What I want to do is to have a function

```
(defun rem (n l) 
   ; code here
)
```

where n is **always** a non-negative integer and l can be an atom/list/null. The function removes the n-th element (one-based indexing) of:

- the list (l) itself
- any-level sub-lists that the original list contains

I reckon using **remove** and **nth** would make this task a piece of cake, but I've yet to have any success.

Any answers/actual code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if you wanted `remove` functionality or `delete` functionality. I'll do the non destructive versions here.

You can make `remove-nth` for one list by making a new list of all the elements before the index, then use the tail of the `cons` you want to remove to share as much structure as possible. Here is an implementation using  [`subseq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_subseq.htm), [`nconc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_nconc.htm), and [`nthcdr`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/f_nthcdr.htm) to show how easy it is without recursion.

```lisp
(defun remove-nth (n list)
  (nconc (subseq list 0 n) (nthcdr (1+ n) list)))

(defparameter *test* (list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6))
(remove-nth 3 *test*) ; ==> (0 1 2 4 5 6)
(remove-nth 0 *test*) ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

A recursive function would look something like this:

```lisp
(defun remove-nth-rec (n list)
  (assert (not (null list)))
  (if (zerop <??>)
      <??>
      (cons <??> (remove-nth-rec <??> <??>))))
```

You can make function that does this on each sublist recursively too. I'd do this with `mapcar`:

```lisp
(defun remove-all-nth (n lol)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (remove-nth n x)) lol))

(remove-all-nth 0 '((a b c) (0 1 2) (I II III))) ; ==> ((b c) (1 2) (II III))
```

A recursive function would look something like this:

```lisp
(defun remove-all-nth-rec (n list)
  (if (null <??>)
      nil
      (cons (remove-nth-rec n <??>)
            (remove-all-nth-rec n <??>))))
```